# KafkaJS reconnecting after initial connection with kafka and kafka connect, throwing error?

Tags: apache-kafka, nestjs, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, kafkajs

I am trying to connect with kafka with my kafka microservice,
[connection configuration kafkajs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZGZp.png)
but throwing following error :
[errors even after initial connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAbOn.png)

Ny best guess it is something regarding my kafka environment ,
which is like following right now:
[kafka setup server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNuxj.png)

It could also be because of how kafka works when configured to work with kafka connect, does it behaviour or environment change.